# Create event delegate to method with custom parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, reflection

I'm struggling to get .Net Reflection to work with the following situation...

(The below is `VB.Net`, but I've tagged this as `C#` in the hope that an answer can be found from a wider audience.  And if the `C#` answer can't be converted to `VB.Net` due to language constraints, at least I know I can re-write it in `C#` if required.)

I'm writing a  .Net 4.5.2 DLL that I can drop into an existing ASP.NET 4.5.2 production website, so I don't need to rebuild the website. In the new DLL I am using Reflection to find a class, add an event delegate and then call a method.

The problem I'm having is that the event delegate needs to bind to a local function with parameter class that also needs to be found via reflection.

In the existing DLL that cannot be rebuilt, I have the following (the following has been written by hand here, and is not copied, so might contain minor typos)...

```vb
Public Class OldClass
   ' A nested class used for the eventargs of the event
   Public Class OldClassEventArgs
     Inherits EventArgs
     Public Property MiscArgs As String = ""
   End Class
   ' Event delegate
   Public Delegate Sub OldClassEventDelegate(ByVal e As OldClassEventsArgs)
   ' The event itself
   Public Event OldClassEvent As OldClassEventDelegate
   ' A method that does things and then raises the event
   Public Sub OldClassMethod(Byval arg1 As String)
     RaiseEvent OldClassEvent(New OldClassEventArgs())
   End Sub
End Class
```

In the new DLL, I want to be able to create an instance of `OldClass`, bind an event handler to `OldClassEvent` and call `OldClassMethod`... with the result that the local event handler is called with the parameter being an instance of `OldClassEventArgs`...

```vb
Public Class MyPage
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Gets the assembly for the existing website DLL
    Dim assem As Assembly = GetAssembly()
    ' Get the type of the class in the existing website
    Dim oldClassType As Type = assem.GetType("OldClass", False, True)
    ' Create an instance of the class
    Dim oldClassObj as Object = Activator.CreateInstance(oldClassType, False)
    ' Get the LOCAL event handler
    Dim eventMethod As MethodInfo = Me.GetType().GetMethod("LocalEventHandler", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    ' Get the event info
    Dim eventInf As EventInfo = logonType.GetEvent("OldClassEvent")
    ' Create the delegate
    Dim del As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInf.EventHandlerType, oldClassObj, eventMethod)
    ' Add the delegate to the event
    eventInf.AddEventHandler(classObj, del)
    ' Get the method to call
    Dim methodInf as MethodInfo = logonType.GetMethod("OldClassMethod", BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    ' Call it
    methodInf.Invoke(oldClassObj, New Object() { "foobar" })
  End Sub

  ' The following CANNOT happen, because OldClassEventArgs needs to be found via reflection!
  Protected Sub LocalEventHandler(ByVal e As OldClass.OldClassEventArgs)
    ' Do something with e.MiscArgs
  End
End Class
```

As you can see in the above code, it's impossible for me to use `OldClass.OldClassEventsArgs` because it doesn't exist in the current context... only via reflection.

**How can I create a method using a class found via reflection as a parameter??**

Even if I have the local handler take `ByVal e As Object` I still get the runtime error of...

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

... on the creation of the `Delgate`.

---

**Update**

Based on comments by @jmcilhinney, I have also tried the following method declaration (using `EventArgs`) and it still results in the same runtime error as before...

```vb
  Protected Sub LocalEventHandler(ByVal e As EventArgs)
  End
```

Comment: All event handlers should have a `sender` parameter of type `Object` and an `e` parameter of type `EventArgs` or a derived type.  If the code has been written properly then `OldClassEventArgs` inherits `EventArgs` and your method can be declared `Protected Sub LocalEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` and it will work.

Comment: You're right that there *should* be a `sender` parameter, but in this case, there isn't... you are also right that the event args **is** inherited from `EventArgs` (I will update the above code shortly to show that).  However, changing the method to `e As EventArgs` still results in the same  runtime error message

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've just rebuilt the system passing through `sender As Object` before the `EventArgs` and it made no difference to the outcome

Comment: Can you not add a reference to the old assembly so that you can use the classes in it directly?

Comment: Unfortunately @Craig that is not possible... plus I now have the above code working, thanks to the answer provided by levent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a delegate instance, we need to use the instance that contains the delegate method.

eventMethod => MethodInfo (LocalEventHandler) is located on MyPage class.

you need change

```
Dim del As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInf.EventHandlerType, oldClassObj, eventMethod)
```

to

```
Dim del As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventInf.EventHandlerType, Me, eventMethod)
```

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute star... so simple!  Now I just have to figure out how to cast the `e As EventArgs` to `OldClassEventArgs`